# Accessible Select List Read all Options

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

HTML5: I have a multi-select list that I need to make accessible. Since it's a native control, it works fine. The problem is that they want the assistive technology to read all of the options when the page is loaded. So far, I have not found a way to make it read them. If they select an option, it will read the text and say option "xx" out of "xx", but it is not enough. Has anyone found a way to make assistive technology read the options upon loading the page? This customer is mainly using JAWS to help navigate the pages.

**Here is the test html that I've been playing around with so far.**

```
<select id="testing" multiple>
   <option value="1">one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
   <option value="3">three</option>
   <option value="4">four</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: You can try with aria live regions
<div aria-live="assertive" hidden>One two three</div>

Comment: Who is "they" in "The problem is that they want the assistive technology to read ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use a native control, you should not reprogram its normal behaviour. That's common accessibility.

You could perfectly add a `label` or an `aria-label` listing all the choices:

```
<label for="testing">
   Choose one or more elements in the list: One two three four
</label>
<select id="testing" multiple>
   <option value="1">one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
   <option value="3">three</option>
   <option value="4">four</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I did. So far, they are happy with the change.